# Repetitive code for a projected field in a lambda

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

I have a simple projection in my code. Taking away the majority of the fields which are not of interest, it looks like the following:

```
var result = employments.Select(x => new EmpListItem
        {
            EndDate = x.EmpRelationship.OrderByDescending(y => y.EndTime).FirstOrDefault().CancelledBeforeTime ? 
                        x.EmpRelationship.OrderByDescending(y => y.EndTime).FirstOrDefault().CancelEndTime : 
                        x.EmpRelationship.OrderByDescending(y => y.EndTime).FirstOrDefault().EndTime,
            JobType = x.JobType
        });
```

I really dislike how I use `x.EmpRelationship.OrderByDescending(y => y.EndTime).FirstOrDefault()` three times. It looks ugly and readability is poor.

Is there a way to use this only once while staying inline? By inline I mean that I don't want to write any code outside of the projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract out that repeat call to a variable inside your `Select`.

```
var result = employments.Select(x => 
{
    var empRelationship = x.EmpRelationship.OrderByDescending(y => y.EndTime).FirstOrDefault();

    return new EmpListItem
    {
        EndDate = empRelationship.CancelledBeforeTime ? 
                      empRelationship.CancelEndTime : 
                      empRelationship.EndTime,
        JobType = x.JobType
    };
});
```

This will also speed up execution.

The trick behind this is remembering you can execute more than just one statement inside a lambda by using `{` and `}`

Comment: I had to write `employments.AsEnumerable.Select`.... since `employments` is of type `IQueryable` (which I should've mentioned in the question). When I did that your solution works perfectly!

Do you know if first converting to `IEnumerable` and then to `IQueryable` is a heavy on the performance side? I need to return an `IQueryable` but as mentioned above it doesn't allow me to write your solution out if `employment` is not of type `IEnumerable`

Comment: I don't know off-hand how the conversion between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` is done, my recommendation is to only worry about it if that section of code becomes a performance bottleneck. Premature optimisation is a sure-fire way to waste your time and ruin your code.

Comment: Cheers:) no performance issues, so I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: I would also point out that `First()` might be a better choice than `FirstOrDefault()`, since there is no null check before accessing properties on `empRelationship`.